# Rect collision on a pygame display; pressing a second key, after collision, causes rect to jump

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm having issues getting this collision to work 100%. If I only press one key at a time, the collision seems to work fine, but if I press a key and continue pressing, while colliding, then press another key, the collision seems to account for both keys at the same time. From researching, it seems like I need to do separate axis calculations, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that, using the algorithm I have for collision. I want this to be procedural style, if possible. If anyone could amend my code, with a working procedural solution, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from math import fabs

pg.init()

width = 600
height = 600

gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
pg.display.set_caption('Block')


white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

clock = pg.time.Clock()
closed = False
FPS = 60
Player_Speed = 200
x, y = 270, 0
vx = 0
vy = 0
collision = False

def Collision(hero, enemy):
    global vx, vy, x, y, collision
    deltay = fabs(block.centery - ENEMY.centery)
    deltax = fabs(block.centerx - ENEMY.centerx)
    if deltay < ENEMY.height and deltax < ENEMY.width:
        collision = True
        if vx > 0:
            vx = 0
            x = ENEMY[0] - block[2] 
        if vx < 0:
            vx = 0
            x = ENEMY[0] + 30
        if vy > 0:
            vy = 0
            y = ENEMY[1] - block[3] 
        if vy < 0:
            vy = 0
            y = ENEMY[1] + 30
    else:
        collision = False


def xy_Text(x, y):
    font = pg.font.SysFont("Courier", 16, True)
    text = font.render("X: " + str(round(x)), True, (0,150,0))
    text1 = font.render("Y: " + str(round(y)), True, (0,150,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text1, (0,14))

while not closed:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            closed = True

        dt = clock.tick(FPS)/1000
        vx, vy = 0, 0

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
            closed = True
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            vx = -Player_Speed
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            vx = Player_Speed
        if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            vy = -Player_Speed
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            vy = Player_Speed
        if vx != 0 and vy != 0:
            vx *= 0.7071
            vy *= 0.7071


    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    ENEMY = pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (270, 270, 30, 30))
    block = pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (0, 150, 0), (x, y, 30, 30))
    xy_Text(x, y)
    x += vx * dt
    y += vy * dt
    Collision(block, ENEMY)
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Collision handling is hard. I would advise you to - instead of trying to reinvent the wheel - use an existing library like Box2d or Pymunk

Comment: I know I can use an existing library, even pygame has collision handling. I'm "reinventing the wheel" for educational purposes. I want to understand how everything works. Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: That's a great motive. For instance, in a force-based approach you could handle collisions by creating auxiliary forces to move colliding objects apart. The number of pressed keys would propably be irrelevant for such a model. The fact that this plays a major role in your question on the other hand implies - from my point of view - that you need more research into how such simulations work.

Comment: [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame - Lab 16: Pygame Platformer Examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?&chapter=example_code_platformer) In one example you can see: 1. move only vertically, 2. check all collisions, 3. move only horizontally, 4. check all collisions again.

Comment: I assume you want to handle collisions with walls, but I'm not sure since you called the one rect `ENEMY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle collisions with walls, move along the x or y axis first, set the player back if s/he collided and then do the same for the other axis. If you use `pygame.Rect`s, you can use their `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` attributes to easily set the player back to the corresponding side of the block.

So check if the player collides with a block and if s/he moved to the right (`vx > 0`), then set `hero.right` to `block.left` and do the same for the other directions. You also have to return the new x and y coords if the player rect was updated.

I suggest to put the blocks (rects) into a `blocks` list which you can pass to the wall collision functions and then just use a for loop.

```
from math import fabs
import pygame as pg


pg.init()

width = 600
height = 600

gameDisplay = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))

white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

clock = pg.time.Clock()
closed = False
FPS = 60
Player_Speed = 200
x, y = 270, 0
vx = 0
vy = 0
# Define the font in the global scope.
FONT = pg.font.SysFont("Courier", 16, True)


# Better don't use global variables.
def handle_horizontal_collisions(hero, blocks, x, vx):
    """Sets the player back to the left or right side."""
    for block in blocks:
        if hero.colliderect(block):
            if vx > 0:
                hero.right = block.left
            elif vx < 0:
                hero.left = block.right
            return hero.x  # Need to update the actual `x` position.
    return x


def handle_vertical_collisions(hero, blocks, y, vy):
    """Sets the player back to the top or bottom side."""
    for block in blocks:
        if hero.colliderect(block):
            if vy > 0:
                hero.bottom = block.top
            elif vy < 0:
                hero.top = block.bottom
            return hero.y  # Need to update the actual `y` position.
    return y


def xy_Text(x, y):
    text = FONT.render("X: " + str(round(x)), True, (0,150,0))
    text1 = FONT.render("Y: " + str(round(y)), True, (0,150,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))
    gameDisplay.blit(text1, (0,14))


# Use pygame.Rects for the player and blocks.
player = pg.Rect(x, y, 30, 30)
# Put the blocks into a list.
blocks = []
for rect in (pg.Rect(200, 200, 60, 30), pg.Rect(230, 230, 60, 30)):
    blocks.append(rect)

dt = 0

while not closed:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            closed = True
        # clock.tick should not be called in the event loop.

    vx, vy = 0, 0
    # key.get_pressed should also not be in the event loop.
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
        closed = True
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
        vx = -Player_Speed
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
        vx = Player_Speed
    if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
        vy = -Player_Speed
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
        vy = Player_Speed
    if vx != 0 and vy != 0:
        vx *= 0.7071
        vy *= 0.7071

    # Game logic.
    x += vx * dt
    player.x = x
    x = handle_horizontal_collisions(player, blocks, x, vx)

    y += vy * dt
    player.y = y
    y = handle_vertical_collisions(player, blocks, y, vy)

    # Rendering.
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    for block in blocks:
        pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, block)
    pg.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (0, 150, 0), player)

    xy_Text(x, y)
    pg.display.update()
    dt = clock.tick(FPS)/1000

pg.quit()
```

Comment: This was the best answer. It does exactly what I ask for, and some, without sacrificing smooth movement. Like the guy above, you, too, separate different sections of code with comments. I will start doing this as well; it makes code look much neater and organized. Thank you for your time, efforts, and advice.

Answer (score 1):

After many changes collision works

I moved

```
x += vx * dt
y += vy * dt
```

into Collision.

I changed organization in code and I always use `Rect()` to keep position and size of player and enemy

I also add second enemy to test how to check collision with many elements.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from math import fabs

# - functions --- (lower_case_names)

def check_collision(player, enemy1, enemy2):
    global player_vx, player_vy

    # --- X ---

    player.x += player_vx * dt

    # enemy 1

    deltay = fabs(player.centery - enemy1.centery)
    deltax = fabs(player.centerx - enemy1.centerx)

    if deltay < enemy1.height and deltax < enemy1.width:
        if player_vx > 0:
            player_vx = 0
            player.x = enemy1.x - player.w
        elif player_vx < 0:
            player_vx = 0
            player.x = enemy1.x + player.w

    # enemy 2

    deltay = fabs(player.centery - enemy2.centery)
    deltax = fabs(player.centerx - enemy2.centerx)

    if deltay < enemy2.height and deltax < enemy2.width:
        if player_vx > 0:
            player_vx = 0
            player.x = enemy2.x - player.w
        elif player_vx < 0:
            player_vx = 0
            player.x = enemy2.x + player.w

    # --- Y ---

    player.y += player_vy * dt

    # enemy 1

    deltay = fabs(player.centery - enemy1.centery)
    deltax = fabs(player.centerx - enemy1.centerx)

    if deltay < enemy1.height and deltax < enemy1.width:
        if player_vy > 0:
            player_vy = 0
            player.y = enemy1.y - player.h
        elif player_vy < 0:
            player_vy = 0
            player.y = enemy1.y + player.w

    # enemy 2

    deltay = fabs(player.centery - enemy2.centery)
    deltax = fabs(player.centerx - enemy2.centerx)

    if deltay < enemy2.height and deltax < enemy2.width:
        if player_vy > 0:
            player_vy = 0
            player.y = enemy2.y - player.h
        elif player_vy < 0:
            player_vy = 0
            player.y = enemy2.y + player.w


def xy_text(screen, x, y):
    font = pg.font.SysFont("Courier", 16, True)

    text = font.render("X: " + str(round(x)), True, (0,150,0))
    screen.blit(text, (0,0))

    text = font.render("Y: " + str(round(y)), True, (0,150,0))
    screen.blit(text, (0,14))

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

FPS = 60

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

player_speed = 200
player_vx = 0
player_vy = 0

player = pg.Rect(270, 0, 30, 30)
enemy1 = pg.Rect(270, 270, 30, 30)
enemy2 = pg.Rect(240, 300, 30, 30)

# - init -
pg.init()

game_display = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('Block')

# - mainloop -

clock = pg.time.Clock()

closed = False
while not closed:

    dt = clock.tick(FPS)/1000

    # - events -

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            closed = True

    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

    player_vx = 0
    player_vy = 0

    if keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
        closed = True
    if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
        player_vx = -player_speed
    if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
        player_vx = player_speed
    if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
        player_vy = -player_speed
    if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
        player_vy = player_speed
    if player_vx != 0 and player_vy != 0:
        player_vx *= 0.7071
        player_vy *= 0.7071

    # - updates -

    check_collision(player, enemy1, enemy2)

    # - draws -

    game_display.fill(WHITE)
    pg.draw.rect(game_display, RED, enemy1)
    pg.draw.rect(game_display, RED, enemy2)
    pg.draw.rect(game_display, (0, 150, 0), player)
    xy_text(game_display, player.x, player.y)
    pg.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the amendments and advice. I liked the way you separated everything with comments. I'll start doing that. The only problem with this code, that I found, was that is slows movement and isn't as smooth. The collision does work, though.

Comment: Is there any way to get this code to work with the smooth movement?

Comment: problem is two `tips(FPS)` - very near one each other - so `dt` gives time between both `tips(FPS)` but not time used to draw elements. Now code works faster.

Comment: if you will have much more objects then checking collision can be problem and there is method "Space partitioning" ("Spatial Partition") so you check collison only with neerest objects - [youtube: 2D grid spatial partitioning basics (speed up collision broad-phase)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HY_SqqaoL4), or [Game Programming Patterns: Spatial Partition](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html)